# How can I pass an object from ngRepeat to Modal in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to pass an object from ngRepeat to a modal window... like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="slot in slots">
    {{ slot }}<br>
    <button ng-click="openModal()">Open</button>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">

    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">{{ slot.time }}</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>body</p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                footer
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</script>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.openModal = function () {
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html'
    })
}
```

What is the correct way to pass the slot to the modal without messing up the scope and causing funky behaviour?  I tried passing the slot in `<button ng-click="openModal(slot)">...` which kind of worked but strange things started happening which led me to believe it wasn't the right thing to do.  Any advice?

Comment: so.. `openModel` or `openModal` ?

Comment: can you share your fix? Did you use resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in the name you gave the identifier for your array of objects.

For example, for the follow array of objects:

```
$scope.myArray = [
    {name:"Tyler", job:"Developer"},
    {name:"Tony", job:"Designer"},
    {name:"Tabby", job:"PM"},
    {name:"Todd", job:"Grunt"}
]
```

Access them like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in myArray">
    <div ng-click="openModal(person)">Push me</div>
</div>
```

Then you have access inside your myFunction function:

```
$scope.openModal = function(person) { console.log(person) };
```